# Receiving Notifications with QWebEngine

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine

I'm trying to develop a small app that opens Messenger , and i need to notify the user when there is a new message

I'm using Qt 5.10 , and i have developed pretty much all the other functionality , i only need to know how to receive notifications from Messenger and than ill handle the rest.
I thought maybe Messenger uses some kind of a JavaScript call when there is a new message , but i'm not sure , i have no experience with this.

PS: i would love to do the same with Discord and MEGA.nz as well , hoping the same principle goes for both Messenger , Discord & MEGA.nz.

This is the main code on MainWindow's constructor:

```
p_UISettings = new QSettings("UISettings.ini" , QSettings::IniFormat);
this->resize(p_UISettings->value("Width" , 776).toInt() , p_UISettings->value("Height" , 508).toInt());

p_TrayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon(":/new/prefix1/Res/Messenger.png") , this);
QAction *Exit_TrayAction = new QAction(QIcon(":/new/prefix1/Res/1470421625_onebit_33.png") , "Close" , 0);
QObject::connect(p_TrayIcon , SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)) , this , SLOT(showHide(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)));
QObject::connect(Exit_TrayAction , SIGNAL(triggered(bool)) , this , SLOT(forceClose()));
QMenu *Tray_Menu = new QMenu;
Tray_Menu->addAction(Exit_TrayAction);
p_TrayIcon->setContextMenu(Tray_Menu);
p_TrayIcon->show();

QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()->setPersistentCookiesPolicy(QWebEngineProfile::ForcePersistentCookies);
QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()->setPersistentStoragePath(QDir::currentPath() + "/Storage/");

ui->View_Widget->setUrl(QUrl("https://www.messenger.com"));
```

Thats pretty much all , the other functions are just events to handle closing + resize thats all.

Comment: What do you mean with *Messenger*? you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc by Messenger i meant Facebook's Messenger (www.messenger.com) , PS: i added my current code

Answer (score 0):

Web Notifications are only supported in Qt WebEngine from Qt 5.13

Comment: so there is no way around this using Qt 5.12

Comment: You could install some javascript to handle it with a webchannel connection, depending on what you need.